# How to determine email address behind Email link on Job page?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I'm interested in emailing a company about a position advertised on Stack Overflow. When I click ***Email*** the browser attempts to open a native email client. The problem is, there is no native email client setup on this machine. When I click ***Exit*** on the setup screen, all windows are closed, including the native client compose window with the email address.

I tried to extract the address from the link by inspecting page elements, but its a URL and not a `mailto:`

```
<a href="/jobs/email-job?jobId=135832" class="mail" rel="nofollow" target="email">
    <svg viewBox="53 381 16 12" width="16" height="12" role="icon" class="icon-email">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M61 389c-.266 0-.5-.094-1-.336L53 385v7c0 .55.45 1 1 1h14c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-7l-7 3.664c-.5.242-.734.336-1 .336zm7-8H54c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v.758l8 4.205 8-4.205V382c0-.55-.45-1-1-1z"></path>
    </svg>
    Email
</a>
```

How do I learn the email address behind a link on the Stack Overflow jobs site?

---

Here is the box with the ***Email*** button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to this *Email* button, right?

[image]

The purpose of this button is actually to share the job by email, for example with someone who you think might be interested in it.

In order to contact the company, please click *ask a question* a little further up:

[image]

Comment: *"The purpose of this button is actually to share the job by email..."* - Forgive my ignorance... then what does the ***Share*** button do? If ***Email*** shares the job, does ***Share*** email the company?

Comment: The share button is for sharing the job on Facebook or Twitter. I guess it would be clearer if "Email" was one of the options under "share", not its own button. I'll bring this up with the team on Monday.